# How to set spacing after a particular row in html table?

Tags: html, css

I have a table and I want to style spacing for every row in the table. I want the gap after the first row to be small (for example 1px) and 20px after the second row. Margin and padding does not seem to work. I also tried cellspacing = 20 but it sets spacing for every cell and I want to style gaps after the rows. How can I achieve that?

This snippet is what I currently have and what I tried :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table cellspacing="20">
  <tr style = "margin-bottom: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px">
    <th style = "padding-bottom: 1px">Month</th>
    <th style = "padding-bottom: 1px">Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style = "margin-bottom: 20px">January</td>
    <td style = "margin-bottom: 20px">$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style = "border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 1px">
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>June</td>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: put the padding on each table cell (`<td>`,`<th>`), not the row

Comment: @zgood I have just edited my post the way you suggested. And I still can not get the gap after the first row to get smaller. Also, the second gap was not displayed correctly using padding so I tried margin. And margin didn't work either.

Comment: the gap(cellspacing or border-spacing) is set for the whole table, in between coll and/or rows but not individually. grid would allow such a thing via margin , not grid-gap. margin doesnt-work for table-cell. transform could help to fake it https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pozNKXw

Comment: All of your answers seems to be helpful. Except that my table is really big so I have to access particular row by id or a class. And nth-of-child is also not suitable since the table is dynamically modified. I also have this style : "border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 1.5em" on my whole table so the css you are all suggesting cannot be overwriten that easily. I will keep as it is for now, maybe later the solution will come

Answer (score 1):

padding is not allowed on table row so you can apply padding to td or you can also add div inside td and give div tag margin bottom.

here, I have taken table inside td and gave margin to table

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="border:0px;">
        <table style="margin-bottom:10px;border:0px;">
          <tr>
            <td>Month</td>
            <td>Savings</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="border:0px;">
        <table style="width:100%;margin-bottom:10px;border:0px;">
          <tr>
            <td >January</td>
            <td>$100</td>
          </tr>
          </table>
         </td>
        </tr>
      <tr style = "border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 20px">
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>June</td>
        <td>$50</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer! But sorry, this is not the correct answer because your solution suggests I should divide my data into two tables. But then the alignment becomes terrible. Even in this example alignment gets ruined. And in my case I have short and long strings in my table so it is not suitable.

Comment: have you tried with div structure with display: table; and display:table-cell properties?

Answer (score 0):

> I want the gap after the first row to be small (for example 1px) and
>   20px after the second row.

You can achieve it by using padding on the td, and with [pseudo selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).
Something like this:

```css
table tr td {padding-top: 20px;}
table tr:nth-of-type(2) td {padding-top: 1px;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>June</td>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Any ideas how to do this by taking id not nth-of-child since my table changes dynamically and is quite big? Important detail: I have border-spacing: 1.5em; on a <table> tag so I need to overwrite it somehow

Comment: Didn't understand the first issue about the dynamically changing content... For the second issue - you can use the border-spacing attribute with !important to override the existing style..